# This is another example of my neverending confusion related to memory and pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, printf, sizeof, conversion-specifier

I am a newbie in C, but I have already watched dozens of videos on YT about how to understand pointers... Unfortunately, it seems my stupid brain is not getting the point about pointers. Could anyone help me to understand why I am getting such values in the output?

The output is: 1-40 256-296 64-104

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int arr1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int arr_size = sizeof(arr1) / sizeof(arr1[0]);
    int arr2[arr_size];
    int arr3[arr_size];
    int *ptr1 = arr1;
    int *ptr2 = arr2;
    int *ptr3 = arr3;
    printf("%u-%u %u-%u %u-%u\n", *ptr1, sizeof(arr1), *ptr2, *ptr2+sizeof(arr2), *ptr3, *ptr3+sizeof(arr3));
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Read a book — a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/15168) — and practice.  Practice will help more than watching videos, IMO.  With pointers, drawing pictures often helps too.

Comment: Tom, on the plus side, you are coding the _arrays_ as `arr...` and _pointers_ as `ptr...`.  It is good to demo that arrays are not pointers and pointers are not arrays.

Answer (score -1):

The arrays `arr2` and `arr3` are not initialized. So their elements have indeterminate values. Outputting uninitialized elements invokes undefined behavior.

Also to output a value of the type `size_t` you need to use the conversion specifier `zu` instead of `u` in a call of `printf`.

So the only valid call of `printf` will look the following way

```
printf("%d-%zu\n", *ptr1, sizeof(arr1) );
```

This call outputs the value of the first element of the array `arr1` by means of the pointer `ptr1` that (value) is equal to `1` and the size of the array itself that can be equal to `40` provided that `sizeof( int )` is equal to `4`.

Comment: Thanks, I will read it carefully, few times, and will see.

Comment: Re “Outputting uninitialized elements invokes undefined behavior”: No, it does not. They will have indeterminate values, so some value will be passed to `printf` for formatting (unless the C implementation has trap representations in that type and the indeterminate value happens to be such a trap representation). Using the value of an uninitialized automatic object that could have been declared `register` has undefined behavior per C 2018 6.3.2.1 2, but arrays and their elements cannot be declared `register`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil And an indeterminate value can be a trap value.  Oh, it is a well defined program.:)

Comment: @EricPostpischil From teh C Standard "5 Certain object representations need not represent a value of the object type. If the stored
value of an object has such a representation and is read by an lvalue expression that does
not have character type, the behavior is undefined. If such a representation is produced
by a side effect that modifies all or any part of the object by an lvalue expression that
does not have character type, the behavior is undefined.50) Such a representation is called
a trap representation."

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: I know what a trap representation is. Common modern C implementations do not have trap representations in the `int` type, and therefore it cannot occur that an indeterminate value has a trap representation. Further, in C implementations where it does, the statements “`*ptr2` has undefined behavior” and “`*ptr2` has an indeterminate value which could cause undefined behavior” are different statements. This answer contains the former, essentially, so it is wrong.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It is not important how modern compilers behave. It is important what is written in the C Standard.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: What is written in the C standard is that implementations may or may not have trap representations. If an implementation does not have trap representations, then `int x[10]; printf("%d\n", x[0]);` does not have undefined behavior; it is required by the standard to format **some** `int` value and print it. Stating “Outputting uninitialized elements invokes undefined behavior” without qualification is false; it is not what the C standard says.

Comment: @EricPostpischil [J.2 Undefined behavior (...) The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is indeterminate](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2).

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: Annex J is non-normative. It is an informational summary, useful for locating things in the normative part of the standard, and it contains errors, such as that one. I have cited the relevant normative part of the standard, C 2018 6.3.2.1 2.

Comment: @EricPostpischil This is what the standard literally **says**. Whether what it says is true or not, I do not judge.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: It is text in the physical document, but it is not part of “the C standard.” If you want to make the point that the text actually appears in the document, fine, but that is worthless. It is not a normative part of the document and is not relevant in determining the meaning of the standard when we have clear language in the normative text of 2018 6.3.2.1 2.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I provided a quote from the section "6.2.6 Representations of types" of the C Standard.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: I addressed that.

Comment: @EricPostpischil See also http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_451.htm

Comment: @EricPostpischil In the quote you provided there is used an example with unsigned char. And moreover until the Standard is not changed you have to follow the Standard.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: Why should I see that? What meaning do you think it has for this discussion?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: (a) I did not provide any quote with an `unsigned char`, and how would that matter anyway?  (b) I am discussing the C standard as it stands. Nor do I or any person have to follow the C standard; it is entirely voluntary. Your answer is wrong; just fix it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil My answer is not wrong. It follows the C Standard.